# How Do I access Outlook GAL properties for each entry

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I Am using Excel VBA to iterate trough Outlook GAL.  I need to be able to access the properties for each item

I am parting from the following code and trying to access the properties from AddressEntry

I have tried different thing using this code but I haven't been able to figure out how to get to the detail of each entry.

```
Private Sub GetAddresses()

    Dim o, AddressList, AddressEntry
    Set o = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set AddressList = o.Session.AddressLists("Global Address List")
    For Each AddressEntry In AddressList.AddressEntries
        . . .
    Next AddressEntry

End Sub
```

I need to get to the properties and extract information and pass it to an excel sheet:

I would have post a picture but don't have the rep.

If I select an item from the GAL and right-click and select properties, that is the information I am trying to retrieve.

```
Last Name,
First Name, 
Alias, 
etc.
```

How do I access this using Excel VBA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser to retrieve the ExchangeUser object: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn320297(v=office.15).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn320297%28v=office.15%29.aspx)